# Resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\frak{S}_3$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

I am looking for the free/projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}[\frak{S}_3]$ where $\frak{S}_3$ is the symmetric group on 3 elements. I am sure it is written somewhere. It seems to be possible to write it but quite tedious, so I just hope it is already in some paper/book.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Sigma_3$ in this context ?

Comment: Symmetric group on three letters.

Comment: I have changed your $\Sigma_3$ into the (more classical) $\frak{S}_3$ notation.

Comment: Much easier to use the modern $S_3.$ Makes the MathJax simpler. @JeanMarie

Comment: You are right; I was sticking to Bourbaki notations...

Comment: Thank you for the edits - however, I am pretty confident that $\Sigma_3$ is also often used to denote the symmetric group (though when I think about it, maybe more in topology and geometry). Anyway - I would be very grateful for any answer or indication!